Calculating Average Land Surface Temperature from Multiple Landsat Rasters
I am trying to solve a problem that I thought would be fairly straightforward, but is producing erroneuos results. I have taken Landsat 8 (Level 2) data from 3 different dates (May 26, Sept 15, Sept 7, all in 2023), of the same tile (PATH: 201, ROW:24). I would like to get an average land surface temperature value in degrees celsius across the three dates. To do this, I have executed the code below which is running fine, but the values that end up in the cels raster are not sensible. They range from about -11 to 0, which does not make sense as a temperature in degrees celsius for the dates chosen. I have followed this article to calculate the LST, but I have made a mistake somewhere and I am unable to spot it. Any help would be hugely appreciated!
library(colorBlindness)
library(terra)
library(sf)
library(ggplot2)
library(ggspatial)
library(readxl)
library(spdep)
library(tmap)
library(tidyverse)
library(grDevices)

# https://data.cdrc.ac.uk/dataset/index-multiple-deprivation-imd
imd <- read_sf("data/english_IMD_2019/English IMD 2019/IMD_2019.shp")

# https://data.cdrc.ac.uk/system/files/Output_Area_Classification_2011/Output_Area_Classification_2011_E37000023.zip
london <- read_sf("data/Output_Area_Classification_2011/Local_Enterprise_Partnerships/E37000023/shapefiles/E37000023.shp")
london_imd <- st_intersection(imd, london)
london_poly <- vect(london)

may_26 <- rast("data/LC08_L2SP_201024_20230526_20230603_02_T1/LC08_L2SP_201024_20230526_20230603_02_T1_ST_B10.TIF")
sept_15 <- rast("data/LC08_L2SP_201024_20230915_20230925_02_T1/LC08_L2SP_201024_20230915_20230925_02_T1_ST_B10.TIF")
sept_7 <- rast("data/LC09_L2SP_201024_20230907_20230913_02_T1/LC09_L2SP_201024_20230907_20230913_02_T1_ST_B10.TIF")

may_26_b4 <- rast("data/LC08_L2SP_201024_20230526_20230603_02_T1/LC08_L2SP_201024_20230526_20230603_02_T1_SR_B4.TIF")
sept_15_b4 <- rast("data/LC08_L2SP_201024_20230915_20230925_02_T1/LC08_L2SP_201024_20230915_20230925_02_T1_SR_B4.TIF")
sept_7_b4 <- rast("data/LC09_L2SP_201024_20230907_20230913_02_T1/LC09_L2SP_201024_20230907_20230913_02_T1_SR_B4.TIF")

may_26_b5 <- rast("data/LC08_L2SP_201024_20230526_20230603_02_T1/LC08_L2SP_201024_20230526_20230603_02_T1_SR_B5.TIF")
sept_15_b5 <- rast("data/LC08_L2SP_201024_20230915_20230925_02_T1/LC08_L2SP_201024_20230915_20230925_02_T1_SR_B5.TIF")
sept_7_b5 <- rast("data/LC09_L2SP_201024_20230907_20230913_02_T1/LC09_L2SP_201024_20230907_20230913_02_T1_SR_B5.TIF")

new_ext <- ext(203985, 444615, 5606985, 5851815)

may_26 <- crop(may_26, new_ext)
sept_15 <- crop(sept_15, new_ext)
sept_7 <- crop(sept_7, new_ext)

may_26_b4 <- crop(may_26_b4, new_ext)
sept_15_b4 <- crop(sept_15_b4, new_ext)
sept_7_b4 <- crop(sept_7_b4, new_ext)

may_26_b5 <- crop(may_26_b5, new_ext)
sept_15_b5 <- crop(sept_15_b5, new_ext)
sept_7_b5 <- crop(sept_7_b5, new_ext)

london_poly <- project(london_poly, crs(may_26))

may_26 <- mask(may_26, london_poly)
sept_15 <- mask(sept_15, london_poly)
sept_7 <- mask(sept_7, london_poly)

may_26_b4 <- mask(may_26_b4, london_poly)
sept_15_b4 <- mask(sept_15_b4, london_poly)
sept_7_b4 <- mask(sept_7_b4, london_poly)

may_26_b5 <- mask(may_26_b5, london_poly)
sept_15_b5 <- mask(sept_15_b5, london_poly)
sept_7_b5 <- mask(sept_7_b5, london_poly)

coll <- c(may_26, sept_15, sept_7)
mos <- app(coll, fun = mean, na.rm = TRUE)

coll_b4 <- c(may_26_b4, sept_15_b4, sept_7_b4)
mos_b4 <- app(coll_b4, fun = mean, na.rm = TRUE)

coll_b5 <- c(may_26_b5, sept_15_b5, sept_7_b5)
mos_b5 <- app(coll_b5, fun = mean, na.rm = TRUE)


RADIANCE_MULT_BAND_10 <- 3.3420E-04
RADIANCE_ADD_BAND_10 <- 0.10000

TOA <- RADIANCE_MULT_BAND_10 * mos + RADIANCE_ADD_BAND_10

K1_CONSTANT_BAND_10 <- 774.8853
K2_CONSTANT_BAND_10 <- 1321.0789

bt <- (K2_CONSTANT_BAND_10 / (log((K1_CONSTANT_BAND_10 / TOA)) + 1)) - 273.15

ndvi <- (mos_b5 - mos_b4) / (mos_b5 + mos_b4)

min_ndvi <- global(ndvi, fun = "min", na.rm = TRUE)[[1]]
max_ndvi <- global(ndvi, fun = "max", na.rm = TRUE)[[1]]

pv <- (ndvi - min_ndvi) / (max_ndvi - min_ndvi)

e <- 0.004 * pv + 0.986

cels <- (bt / (1 + (0.00115 * bt / 1.4388) * log(e)))


plot(
    cels,
    col = Blue2Orange10Steps,
    xlim = c(255000, 317000),
    ylim = c(5685000, 5734000),
)

As stated, I tried to follow this article, and was expecting that the code above would correctly calculate the average LST, in degrees celsius, across the three dates chosen.

Have a look on pv <- (ndvi - min_ndvi) / (max_ndvi - min_ndvi) and the original equation.

Thank you for the help! I have fixed this, but the calculations still seem to be erroneous.

Can you please edit your question by changing the code into a minimal, self-contained, reproducible example. That is, provide some simple example data with code or with data that ships with R (see the examples in the packages and on this site), remove other pre-processing (crop, mask, project), and only list the packages you need. It is also helpful to show what you expect the result to be (for example for the values of once cell).  I note that you do things band by band where you could do them together in, e.g. mean(may_26[[4:5]], sept_15[[4:5]])

The relationship between TOA radiance and LST is not simply linear. You should therefore not take the average radiance from the 3 images to then apply the formulas once. Instead you should calculate the LST for each of the images separately and only take the average at the final step.
Something like this:
coll <- c(may_26, sept_15, sept_7)
<<< calculate TOA, BT, NDVI, PV, e and cels for each layer>>>
cels <- app(cels, fun = mean, na.rm = TRUE)

